# Dynamically create a fake dataset based on the subset of another (real) dataset

Tags: python, pandas, random, dynamic, faker

I've got a few datasets and for each, I'd like to create a fake dataset that is kind of a representative of that dataset. I need to do it dynamically, only based on the type of data (numeric, obj)

Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# Create a dictionary with columns as lists
data = {
    'ObjectColumn1': [f'Object1_{i}' for i in range(1, 11)],
    'ObjectColumn2': [f'Object2_{i}' for i in range(1, 11)],
    'ObjectColumn3': [f'Object3_{i}' for i in range(1, 11)],
    'NumericColumn1': [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(10)],
    'NumericColumn2': [random.uniform(1.0, 10.0) for _ in range(10)],
    'NumericColumn3': [random.randint(1000, 2000) for _ in range(10)],
    'NumericColumn4': [random.uniform(10.0, 20.0) for _ in range(10)]
}

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Let's say the above dataset has m (=3) object columns and n (=4) numeric columns.
the dataset has x (=10) rows.
I'd like to create a **fake dataset of N (=10,000) rows**, so that:

1. ObjectColumn1, ObjectColumn2, ..., and ObjectColumn_m in the fake dataset are random selections of entries in ObjectColumn1, ObjectColumn2, ..., and ObjectColumn_m of data respectively
2. ExtraObjectColumn in the fake dataset is an added fake column, which is a random selection of a list(e.g. list = [ran1, ran2, ran3])
3. all NumericColumns in the fake data are a randomly generated number that is between the minimum and median of each of those columns in data respectively.
   for example, NumericColumn1 in the fake data would be a randomly generated data between (3 and 71.5)
4. I don't want columns to be hard-coded. imagine m and n and x and N are all dynamic. I need to use this on many multiple datasets and the function needs to detect the object and numeric columns and do the above dynamically. The only column that is NOT dynamic is the ExtraObjectColumn, which needs to be given a list to be created from.
5. Obviously, I need this to be reasonable performance. N is usually a large number (at least 10,000)

here's how fake_data should look like if N = 4

[image]

Comment: The desired output is unclear, can you please provide an example output that matches the shown input for `N=10`?

Comment: Is sampling from an input dataset allowed? If so, you could just use [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

Comment: For reproducibilty, can you please specify which [`np.random.seed`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) have you used ?

Comment: @mozway, I've added a sample data for N=4.  Please note that this will including oversampling for objects.... the object columns are categorical and they're limited. the solution needs to oversample the selection (randomly selecting over and over from the limited entries in each column)

Comment: @Timeless, i noticed too late that I didn't use a seed. Unfortunately I can't reproduce.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira you can always regenerate, we don't need the images, just remove them and provide the text version of the data

Comment: (why opting for posting dataframes as images in this case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, something like this should do what you want. It separates the input dataframe into numeric and other columns, then takes random samples as described in the question from those columns, finally adding a list of extra data as a random sample from the supplied list:

```
def make_fake_data(df, N, extra):
    df_obj = df.select_dtypes('object')
    obj_out = pd.DataFrame({ col : np.random.choice(df_obj[col], N) for col in df_obj.columns })
    df_num = df.select_dtypes('number')
    num_out = pd.DataFrame({ col : np.random.uniform(np.nanmin(df_num[col]), np.nanmedian(df_num[col]), N) for col in df_num.columns })
    ext_out = pd.DataFrame({ 'ExtraObjectColumn' : random.choices(extra, k=N) })
    return pd.concat([obj_out, num_out, ext_out], axis=1)
```

Sample usage:

```
make_fake_data(df, 20, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Sample output:

```
   ObjectColumn1 ObjectColumn2 ObjectColumn3  ...  NumericColumn3  NumericColumn4  ExtraObjectColumn
0      Object1_4     Object2_1     Object3_4  ...     1322.269370       14.502498                  d
1      Object1_6     Object2_5     Object3_5  ...     1314.941227       12.478253                  c
2      Object1_6     Object2_7     Object3_7  ...     1418.271732       11.214247                  a
3      Object1_4     Object2_9     Object3_9  ...     1269.408303       11.404303                  c
4      Object1_3     Object2_6     Object3_4  ...     1426.038132       14.251836                  a
5      Object1_1     Object2_2     Object3_1  ...     1212.806903       14.750310                  c
6     Object1_10     Object2_7     Object3_1  ...     1294.254746       10.692256                  d
7      Object1_1     Object2_7     Object3_3  ...     1232.854020       10.438323                  c
8      Object1_5     Object2_5     Object3_7  ...     1205.779688       14.763409                  c
9      Object1_7     Object2_6     Object3_2  ...     1287.248660       10.384493                  b
10     Object1_4     Object2_2     Object3_1  ...     1237.738855       14.054841                  b
11     Object1_7     Object2_3     Object3_5  ...     1176.494651       12.869827                  c
12     Object1_5     Object2_1    Object3_10  ...     1101.036149       10.978762                  b
13     Object1_5     Object2_6     Object3_7  ...     1430.060873       13.473017                  c
14     Object1_1     Object2_1     Object3_7  ...     1416.556459       12.281628                  c
15     Object1_3     Object2_8     Object3_3  ...     1190.239080       15.257389                  b
16     Object1_6     Object2_9     Object3_5  ...     1101.712808       10.551654                  b
17     Object1_1    Object2_10     Object3_4  ...     1453.687960       15.070104                  b
18     Object1_6     Object2_2     Object3_2  ...     1139.413534       11.744450                  b
19     Object1_7     Object2_7     Object3_2  ...     1080.682206       13.962322                  b
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this very neat solution. this works on the example dataset, but i get the following error on my real dataset which is quite large:

File mtrand.pyx:1155, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.uniform()

OverflowError: Range exceeds valid bounds

Comment: the obj_out is no problem. it's the num_out that fails.

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira hmmm... that would suggest you've got some infinite or nan values in the data perhaps?

Comment: yes yes, I do :-D

Comment: Ah, I see the other solution used `describe` to get around that. I've edited my code to use `nanmin` and `nanmedian` so that should resolve that problem.

Comment: thank you, that works now and it's really fast. I'll choose this as the answer. Many thanks!

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira no worries - I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I noticed there is a case where the nanmin and nanmedian return NaN.
I changed my code to the following to cover those cases as well:

num_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {col: np.random.uniform(np.nanmin(df_num[col]), np.nanpercentile(df_num[col], 50), n)
        if not df_num[col].isnull().all() else None
     for col in df_num.columns})

Comment: @Ankhnesmerira I guess that would happen if every value in the column was `NaN`. Feel free to edit the answer if you want to include that information in it to make it more useful to others who find this.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use :

```
def fakeit(df, N, s=1):
    np.random.seed(s)
    
    rans = ["ran1", "ran2", "ran3"]
    objs = df.select_dtypes("object"); nums = df.select_dtypes("number")
    
    mim = nums.describe().loc[["min", "50%"]].to_dict("list")
    
    fake_objs = (objs.sample(frac=N/len(df), replace=True, ignore_index=True)
                 .assign(ExtraObjectColumn= np.random.choice(rans, size=N)))
    
    fake_nums = (pd.DataFrame({nc: np.random.uniform(*mm, N)
                               for nc,mm in mim.items()}))
    
    return pd.concat([fake_objs, fake_nums], axis=1) # or assign back to df

out = fakeit(df, 10_000)
```

Output :

```
print(out) # with `df` seeded at 0

# 4.19 ms ± 23.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

     ObjectColumn1 ObjectColumn2  ... NumericColumn3 NumericColumn4
0        Object1_6     Object2_6  ...    1026.454938      15.001035
1        Object1_9     Object2_9  ...    1112.569853      12.358510
2       Object1_10    Object2_10  ...    1303.267506      13.656933
3        Object1_6     Object2_6  ...    1380.363296      12.951402
4        Object1_1     Object2_1  ...    1106.091309      14.267152
...            ...           ...  ...            ...            ...
9995    Object1_10    Object2_10  ...    1188.281480      16.635908
9996     Object1_5     Object2_5  ...    1200.956953      13.403647
9997     Object1_6     Object2_6  ...    1271.411811      13.575587
9998     Object1_4     Object2_4  ...    1358.510617      16.788902
9999     Object1_6     Object2_6  ...    1387.046206      16.500843

[10000 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: This worked and it was super fast! thanks a million

Comment: this code works great and it's very fast. It does however fail with NaN values in the columns. Is there a way to exclude NaN values so I don't get the same error as I did with the other solution? :)